# JMeter JavaSampler : How to invoke methods from external jars?

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, performance-testing

Just to give you a context of what i want to achieve :

My functional test team have a java library, which comprises of HTTP calls, based out of REST architecture. I basically want to re-use the jars and invoke methods at higher concurrency. I just wanted to know how this can be achieved using JMeter's JavaSampler?

Example : Lets say I want to do a 100 user login and log-out test, and my jar provides me with the login and logout functionality, then how would my test look like? Any pointers around this would be very helpful for me to get started.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1 - Using [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)**

1. Add the jar(s) which implement your functionality somewhere to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick them up
3. Add [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to your Test Plan, make sure you choose `groovy` as a language and make sure `Cache compiled script if available` box is checked
4. Put the code you want to run in parallel into "Script" area and use JMeter [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to set up the concurrency.

---

**Option 2 - Using [Java Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request)**

Create your own class implementing [JavaSamplerClient](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/JavaSamplerClient.html) interface and create your own overrides of the [`setupTest()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/JavaSamplerClient.html#setupTest-org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSamplerContext-), [`getDefaultParameters`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/JavaSamplerClient.html#getDefaultParameters--) and especially [`runTest()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/JavaSamplerClient.html#runTest-org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSamplerContext-) methods. You can see the following existing classes for reference:

- [JavaTest](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/src/protocol/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/test/JavaTest.java)
- [SleepTest](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/src/protocol/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/test/SleepTest.java)

---

**Option 3 - Using [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)**

JMH stands for [Java Microbenchmark Harness](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-performance/jmh.html) so if you just need to measure method execution timings you can do it even without JMeter, check out [Getting Started With JMH](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-performance/jmh.html#your-first-jmh-benchmark) guide for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Place you jar files in the `lib` folder inside your jmeter folder.

restart and just try importing the corresponding classes.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me with BeanShell post-processors (jmeter 3.2):

1. Put your external jar files in your lib\ext folder
2. Restart jmeter
3. Import packages in a BeanShell script

I am then able to reference the relevant classes in my script.

Answer (score -1):

Can add the Jar file in the Test Plan

Check this [link](https://qautomation.blog/2019/07/08/how-to-use-jar-file-in-jmeter/). which has step by step detail for using an external jar